# call a web page from c#

Tags: c#

I wana to call a web page and don't need response from page. just call page.
How can i do that in c#?
thanks alot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx).

Just call the OpenRead() and don't do anything with the response.

Comment: To save resources, do HEAD rather than GET so it doesn't send the entire response.